# Website to help identify set(s) from approximately 20 bags of LEGO?

Tags: set-identification

I bought a storage unit at auction. There were approx 20 sealed bags of LEGO in the unit. Each bag has a number on it. I'm trying to find out if I have a complete set so I may sell them. Is there a site I can go to to find out? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

[Brickset](https://brickset.com/sets) is a database of Lego sets. You can search for set numbers and see if they match what you have. It also provides full parts lists so you can see if your kits are complete or not.